# Power of a Sr-90 RTG

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, power, radioactivity

I am trying to make sense of the numbers that I have found in a scientific paper (DOI:10.4236/ojbiphy.2013.31A011).

> [image: 1]

As can be seen on the photo, it is written that the mass, which I am pretty sure is referring to the mass of strontium, is $0.26 \;\text{kg}$ and the heat output is $230 \;\text{W}$. However, I have calculated myself and also found a reference (https://atomicinsights.com/rtg-heat-sources-two-proven-materials/), that agrees that $1 \;\text{g}$ of strontium-90 isotope produces $0.46 \;\text{W}$ of power. This does not make sense as according to that number, $0.26 \;\text{kg}$ strontium-90 should produce $260 \times 0.46= 119.6 \;\text{W}$ of heat.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Don't forget that the Yttrium also undergoes (rapid) beta decay, releasing more energy.

Comment: 90Sr->90Y is 546keV, 90Y->90Zr is 2280keV - the second occurs much faster (60 hours) than the first (28.9 yrs), so is effectively simultaneous. Rerun your numbers assuming 2826keV released for each 90Sr decay. You get much closer.

Comment: @JonCuster thanks for your response. When I take into account the subsequent decay of Yttrium-90 and assume that one strontium-90 atom releases the energy of 2826 keV , I get that the wattage per gram is 2.3 watts, corresponding to 2.3 x 260 = 598 watts, which is still not what's in the table.

Comment: Indeed - I was wondering if there is (a) some de-rating going on to account for power output over timescales on the order of the half-life, and (b) possible losses. At least it gets you closer.

Answer (score 2):

Strontium-90 produces around 0.95 W/g.  However strontium metal is not normally used as a source of heat as it is too chemically reactive.  Strontium titanate is often used instead as it is much less reactive.  Because it is only around half strontium by mass the heat output is about 0.46 W/g.  The presence of other, non radioactive isotopes can reduce the specific heat production still further.  Non-radioactive strontium-88 would normally be present in fission product strontium, in similar amounts to the strontium-90, and is not easy to separate.  Fission product strontium is the only practical source of strontium-90.  If the fission product strontium has not been left to decay for long enough strontium-89 can also be present.  This will increase the specific heat production because of a similar decay energy but much shorter half-life of around 51 days.  The figures for energy production here include an amount for the decay of Yttrium-90 but do not add up to the total decay energy because around half of the decay energy is taken away by an antineutrino and lost because antineutrinos interact only very slightly with normal matter such as the shielding which converts the energy of the beta particles from radioactive decay to heat.